# Haw can I create class of generic type?

Tags: python, typing

I need to construct generic class with using typing.TypeVar, and than create in this class objects of generic types.

So, I need something like this

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

class MyClass(Generic[T]):
    def create(self) -> T:
        created_obj = T() # Exception
        return created_obj

my_list_class = MyClass[list]()
new_list = my_list_class.create()

my_dict_class = MyClass[dict]()
new_dict = my_dict_class.create()
```

So, I expected, that it would work, but it raised exception, that you can't call TypeVar.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that type hints are completely ignored at runtime. So this means that even if the type checker infers that some particular instance of your class is of type `MyClass[List[Any]]`, it'll still be just a `MyClass` at runtime. In particular, every occurrence of `T` will *not* be somehow automagically replaced with the bound type.

Instead, you'll need to provide the desired type at runtime yourself:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Type

T = TypeVar('T')

class MyClass(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, type_factory: Type[T]) -> None:
        self._type_factory = type_factory

    def create(self) -> T:
        return self._type_factory()

# Note: we no longer need to explicitly fill in the generic params, since the
# type checker now has enough info to infer this for us.
my_list_class = MyClass(list)
new_list = my_list_class.create()

my_dict_class = MyClass(dict)
new_dict = my_dict_class.create()
```

If you want your code to be even more precise and generalize a bit better, you could have the type of `type_factory` be `Callable[[], T]` instead of `Type[T]`.